# Huge Hashtable sorting - number of values - 553685

Tags: java, sorting, hashtable

I created a hashmap to store occurence of words in multiple files like 10,000 text files. Then i wanted to sort them from hashmap and print top 10 words. Hashmap is defined as,

```
      Hashtable <String, Integer> problem1Counter = new Hashtable<String, Integer> ();
```

When i kept the files to around 1000, i was able to get top ten words using a simple sorting like this,

```
String[] keysProblem1 = (String[]) problem1Counter.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
  Integer [] valuesProblem1 =  (Integer[])problem1Counter.values().toArray(new Integer[problem1Counter.size()]);
```

int kk = 0;
     String ii = null;

```
    for (int jj = 0; jj < valuesProblem1.length ; jj++){
        for (int bb = 0; bb < valuesProblem1.length; bb++){
            if(valuesProblem1[jj] < valuesProblem1[bb]){
            kk = valuesProblem1[jj];
            ii = keysProblem1[jj];
            valuesProblem1[jj] = valuesProblem1[bb];
            keysProblem1[jj] = keysProblem1[bb];
            valuesProblem1 [bb] = kk;
            keysProblem1 [bb] = ii;}}}
```

So the above method is not working when hashtable has more than 553685 values. So can anyone suggest and show a better method to sort them? I'm a newbie to java but had worked in actionscript, so i was a bit comfortable. 
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Does it throw an exception?  If so, what is it?

Comment: As an aside: do you need problem1Counter to be synchronised, by the way?  If not, you might find `HashMap<String, Integer>` a better fit.

Comment: @Martin It just keeps running, i waited more than a couple of minutes. No error at all, so i thought of improving it better.

Comment: Sounds like it's just too slow.  Can you put a System.out.println(Integer.toString(jj)) between your two for loops to confirm?

Comment: @Martin i added print statement - it shows 1, 2, 3 ,4 but very slow. Is there any java memory setting i should consider?

Comment: I wonder how you discovered that it fails exactly at 553686+ values =)

Comment: @AbhilashMuthuraj It's just an algorithmic efficiency thing.  I've updated my answer with an explanation of why Cory and my solutions work, but yours doesn't.  It's nothing to do with memory settings.  You're just comparing every element against every other element, which gets slow.

Comment: @Martin thanks for explanation, i got problem cleared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a better way of doing the sort, I'd do it like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> counter = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    // [... Code to populate hashtable goes here ...]
    // 

    // Extract the map as a list
    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(counter.entrySet());

    // Sort the list of entries.
    Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> first, Entry<String, Integer> second) {
        // This will give a *positive* value if first freq < second freq, zero if they're equal, negative if first > second.
        // The result is a highest frequency first sort.
        return second.getValue() - first.getValue();
        }
    });

    // And display the results
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : entries.subList(0, 10))
        System.out.println(String.format("%s: %d", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }

}
```

**Edit explaining why this works**

Your original algorithm looks like a variant of [Selection Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), which is an O(n^2) algorithm.  Your variant does a lot of extra swapping too, so is quite slow.

Being O(n^2), if you multiply your problem size by 10, it will typically take 100 times longer to run.  Sorting half a million elements needs to do 250 billion comparisons, many of which will lead to a swap.

The built-in sort algorithm in Collections#sort is a lightning fast variant of [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort), which runs in O(n.log(n)) time.  That means that every time you multiply the problem size by 10, it only takes about 30 times as long.  Sorting half a millon elements only needs to do about 10 million comparisons.

This is why experienced developers will advise you to use library functions whenever possible.  Writing your own sort algorithms can be great for learning, but it takes a lot of work to implement one as fast and flexible as what's in the library.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem starts when you split up `keys` and `values` and try to keep the things at each index connected yourself.  Instead, keep them coupled, and sort the `Map.Entry` objects java gives you.

I'm not sure this compiles, but it should give you a start.

```
// HashMap and Hashtable are very similar, but I generally use HashMap.
HashMap<String, Integer> answers = ...

// Get the Key/Value pairs into a list so we can sort them.
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> listOfAnswers =
    new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(answers.entrySet());

// Our comparator defines how to sort our Key/Value pairs.  We sort by the
// highest value, and don't worry about the key.
java.util.Collections.sort(listOfAnswers,
    new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
        public int compare(
                Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1,
                Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
            return o2.getValue() - o1.getValue();
        }
    });

// The list is now sorted.
System.out.println( String.format("Top 3:\n%s: %d\n%s: %d\n%s: %d", + 
        listOfAnswers.get(0).getKey(), listOfAnswers.get(0).getValue(), 
        listOfAnswers.get(1).getKey(), listOfAnswers.get(1).getValue(), 
        listOfAnswers.get(2).getKey(), listOfAnswers.get(2).getValue()));
```

Comment: haha +1 as well, and reading yours made me realize I had o1 - o2 when I needed o2 - o1!

Comment: this was efficient way of dealing with hashmap. Thanks!

Comment: @CoryKendall: I don't think you need to implement Comparator.equals do you?  You'll get the implicit Object.equals without it (which does a reference comparison).  I'm fairly new to Java though, so am wondering if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

- create an inner class Word that implements Comparable
- override public int compareTo(Word w) to make it use occurrences
- create an array of words of the size of your HashMap
- fill the array iterating through the HashMap
- call Arrays.sort on the array

Alternatively, since you only need the top 10, you can just iterate through your Words and maintain a top 10 list as you go along.